# Ember.js: {{render}} does set 'content', but does not set 'model'

Tags: ember.js

From my main handlebars dashboard template I am rendering multiple templates in a loop, setting the model as following

`{{#each forecastDispatch in forecastDispatches}}
  {{render "balance.forecastDispatch" forecastDispatch}}
{{/each}}`
 
The dashboard combines multiple models and renders them on the same page/route.

From logging to the console, I can see that the `BalanceForecastDispatchController` controller gets instantiated correctly for each render call and the `forecastDispatch` model of type `DispatchType` is set as `content`, but not as `model`, `model` is still `undefined`. As the model is not populated properly, passing data to lower level components does not work. I thought that the `model` is just an alias/proxy for `content`, hence I am quite surprised.

What am I missing here? Any help is really appreciated, I am trying to solve this for quite some time now, but cannot find the culprit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was caused by snippets in my Handlebars template which were not commented out properly. As a result, one extra instance of the `BalanceForecastDispatchController` was created by Ember. This controller had off course no model/content assigned to it. In the Chrome Ember-inspector the controller was shown without a model.